# Event when value in QSettings changes?

Tags: android, qt, qsettings

I am not sure how exactly to project settings changes immediatelly onto my application. One way would be to listen on some `QEvent` using [`eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).

Is that an option? Is there any such event? If listening on event is bad idea, what's the correct solution?

Answer (score 3):

`QSettings` will not notify you when a change occurs. If you want to handle the event when settings are actually changed, you should setup a `QFileSystemWatcher` for the `QSettings::fileName()` file.

Another (probably cleaner) solution is to create a wrapper class that defines a proper signal, and emits it whenever you update your settings through it.

Comment: Qt doesn't always write the settings in the file right away, so this would probably not work.

Comment: If you create a QSettings instances as a local variable to update your settings, then destructor will save the changes. Or you can call `sync()` manually where you update the settings. Probably, creating a wrapper class with properly design signal is a cleaner solution.

Comment: I use a settings manager class.  Not sure if it's the best design, but for your common widgets, you just add it to the manager and it handles all of the connections, setValue(), value() calls and whatnot.  You could easily emit a signal when something changes within that.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently feel this need as well, so I wrote some code to handle settings with notifications quickly. The technique only works if the app itself is the only one writing to the settings file/registry. What I do is define my settings class with some macros:

```
L_DECLARE_SETTINGS(LQuickSettings, new QSettings(QSL("settings.ini"), QSettings::IniFormat))
L_DEFINE_VALUE(int, appWidth, 200)
L_DEFINE_VALUE(int, appHeight, 200)
L_DEFINE_VALUE(int, appX, 100)
L_DEFINE_VALUE(int, appY, 100)
L_END_CLASS
```

this generates setters, getters and signals. I then create as many instances as I want:

```
LQuickSettings quickSettings;
quickSettings.set_appWidth(500);
```

Signals are emitted from a specific instance that you can get like this:

```
LQuickSettings& settings = LQuickSettings::notifier();
```

I typically expose this instance to QML, so I can use my settings with properties:

```
settings.appWidth = "Some string";
```

Signals will arrive whatever instance is used to set. As an example:

```
Window {
    [...]

    Connections {
        target: settings
        onAppWidthChanged: (w) => console.log("App width saved:", w)
        onAppHeightChanged: (h) => console.log("App height saved:", h)
    }

    Binding { target: settings; property: "appWidth"; value: width }
    Binding { target: settings; property: "appHeight"; value: height }
    Binding { target: settings; property: "appX"; value: x }
    Binding { target: settings; property: "appY"; value: y }
}
```

I find this technique quicker to write then using QSettings directly. Also, it remains compatible with QSettings because it uses QSettings.

You can find an example here: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils/tree/master/LQtUtilsQuick.
This is the library: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils.
You only need this header for these macros: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils/blob/master/lqtutils_settings.h.
The project is open source and free to use.